# What is the best way to debug cordova apps?

Tags: cordova, debugging

I have a very big mobile app that should work well on android and ios.

I have iphone and windows on my computer, not a mac.

When I have to check my android app its simple, just using `chrome://inspect/#devices`

Which is great (perhaps there are better ways?), but I need the same debugging tool for the iphone.

What is the approach needed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the level of "debug" you want to perform.  A fairly robust solution would be to use Oracle virtualbox, create a VM to run osX from, and then to use Safari to emulate an iPhone(x) where you can test your app for apple ecosystem from.

There's a really good article on [here].(https://blog.udemy.com/xcode-on-windows/ "XCode on Windows: How to Develop for Mac or iOS on a PC")

Comment: great answer, let's hear some more guys... maybe those who developed lots of phonegap apps in the past, thx mike for the input

Comment: Well, using a virtualbox is not allowed by mac OS X EULA, and why would you use safari to emulate an iPhone if you have the iOS simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is buying a mac and using the safari web inspector

Another option is, if you are using phonegap build, using their [remote debugging tools](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/debugging_remote_debugging_tools.md.html#Remote%20Debugging%20Tools)